# Passing the View class object as a parameter to the method invoked by a button (View view)

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to create an app for Android, and I follow this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

there is a part

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
}
```

then I followed this tutorial and everything worked, untill I remove parameter `View view`

my question is just why everytime I remove it, so the function just be:

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage() {
    // Do something in response to button
}
```

and I run the app, it forced close.

could anyone enlighten me? thank you

Comment: Hi View parameter defines the button widget and it will get the id of button widget in view parameter. SO you need to put view parameter in sendMessage() method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the method (typically called `onClick(View view)`) method takes a parameter (the View it is associated with). see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html for more information on the function. if you leave off the parameter you wouldn't expect it to work, would you?

Answer (score 13):

If you look carefully in the XML, you'll see the following attribute on the button:

```
android:onClick="sendMessage"
```

This attribute means that when the button is clicked, message

```
public void sendMessage(View view)
```

is invoked.  This is due to the fact that `onClick` method in the `OnClickListener` interface requires a parameter of type `View`.  When you remove the parameter, android still attempts to call method `sendMessage(View view)` but that method does not exist any more, therefore you get a force-close.

Parameter `view` is the actual view (button in your case) that was clicked. With this, you can assign multiple buttons to invoke the same method and inside the method check which button was clicked.

If you want to have the method without the parameters, then you should assign it in the code instead of the XML.  Change your XML to be

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:id="@+id/send_button" />
```

(Note that `android:onClick` attribute is now removed and `android:id` is added.)  Then in your activity in `onCreate` method you would add the following line:

```
this.findViewById(R.id.send_button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sendMessage();
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is quite a bit more code to write, but it does provide you with more flexibility should you need it.

Answer (score 2):

When you put this kind of thing in your xml :

```
android:onClick="sendMessage"
```

The android framework will add an OnClickListener on your button. This "automatically" generated OnclickListener will try to call a method named "sendMessage" with one single argument of type View.

If this method doesn't exists it simply crash.