# button press in Android app creates casting error

Tags: android, view, casting

I am new to android development, and have been trying to use the beginner's tutorial as my starting point for developing a simple app. There is one screen, with an image, a row of four buttons, a textbox for the user to enter a pin, and a textview to display results.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView1"
       android:contentDescription="@string/image"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/skytrek"
       />

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="@string/button_today"
        android:onClick="today_click" />

            <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="@string/button_tomorrow"
        android:onClick="tomorrow_click" /> 

            <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="@string/button_this_week"
        android:onClick="this_week_click" /> 

          <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="@string/button_next_week"
        android:onClick="next_week_click" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/init_message"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

I have code to deliver the results I want based on the button pressed - all fine. But then I wanted the user to enter a PIN as well as pressing a button, so I added the EditText control. This threw the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(28578): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

**My Java class:**

```
private String content = null;  
private TextView textView1;
private EditText editText1;

public void today_click(View view) {
    getPage("today");
}
public void tomorrow_click(View view) {
    getPage("tomorrow");
}
public void this_week_click(View view) {
    getPage("thisweek");
}
public void next_week_click(View view) {
    getPage("nextweek");
}

public void getPage(String strParam) {

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String message = editText1.getText().toString();

    if (message.equals("4567")) {

                content = "PIN recognised";
    } else {
        content = "PIN not recognised";
    }
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView1.setText(content);
}
```

I thought I had done something silly, using the name of a TextView instead of an EditText control, but I can't find it if I have.

The error is being thrown at the line

```
getPage("thisweek");
```

I didn't understand how this line involved views of any sort, but of course the function heading

```
this_week_click(View view)
```

does, and when I changed the order of the TextView and the EditText in the XML file (so that the TextView comes first), the error disappeared. It is as if the "view" being passed is not the button, but the nearest widget to the button. I have read

[existence of parameter (View view)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971026/existence-of-parameter-view-view)

but it only seems to confirm my (mis)understanding that a button should be passed as the view parameter. I have also tried cleaning the project, and building a completely new project. What on earth is causing the casting error?

Comment: Which line does it crash?

Comment: not intialize any thing in any function,done initialization in on create

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse, go to the menu voice "Project" and select "Clean"

Sometimes Eclipse has some problem with ids, by cleaning the project you regenerate them..

Comment: I did say I had tried cleaning - but I didn't realise I needed to do it *everytime* I changed the XML! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Everytime if you make any changes in xml or any interchange of position of views in xml or change of id's,you need to clean build your project.If not you will get this exception.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I have tested your code, your code is fine. Please clean your project from

select your project then click on Project and then Clean and also check the Build Automatically . Your auto generated class R is not generated properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project and run it again..
Eclipse -> Project menu ->Clean

It is because eclipse gets confused when we play around in the xml file ;)