# Can't understand the View view parameter

Tags: java, android, android-view

I am learning android development from [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
// Do something in response to button
}
```

The sendMessage message method contains a parameter 'View view'? What is a View object and what does it do?

Why is it passed to the method as a parameter and where does it come from?

Comment: Sooo many redundant answers here ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971026/existence-of-parameter-view-view

Comment: Even a duplicate?! This is madness!

Answer (score 6):

While writing a click event you might need to know which object is clicked.
In android mostly all the `UI` components will extend `View` Class.

So you are getting the instance here

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
// Do something in response to button
}
```

In android we can handle click events by two ways

**First way**

Providing the method in xml itself. For example

```
android:onClick="sendMessage"
```

This is how it happens in the example provided by him.

**Second way**

We can extend an `onClickListener` in the `Activity` or `Fragment` and we should override `onClick` method.

See the question "[existence of parameter (View view)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971026/existence-of-parameter-view-view)" for further references.

Comment: ya click event.. The method he referred is called by the Click event. updated my answer for you clarification..

Comment: **onClick()** is perfect,but linking **click event** with **sendMessage()** is doubtful here

Comment: sendMessage is just a name given in android developers site as this example is based on sending message while clicking a send button. Kindly refer the link given in the question

Comment: I too got confused by the name. But after referring the example I found its just a click event..

Answer (score 2):

A View object in Android app development is the building block for a user interface. They are used to create things onscreen for a user to interact with.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/overview.html

Edit:

In your case, when the Send button is clicked and it calls the sendMessage function, it passed the View object of the Send button (it passes the View of the object that called the method).

Comment: You had asked on another answer: "what is passed to the method by this parameter?" I have updated my answer to reflect this. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter is the clicked button, that's all. It actually says so in the link that you provided :/

> Specifically, the method must:
>
> Be public
>
> Have a void return value
>
> Have a View as the only parameter (this will be the View that was clicked)

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you should have understanded the following method, because it is the basic parameter we often used.

```
public void sendName(String name) {
   //some stuff
}
```

And this method will be called when the sendName() appeared next time. The only difference is the sendMessage will be called when you click the button, as button is a view exactly, so you have to use View class instead of String class.

Answer (score 0):

- sendMessage is a method name
- View is your class
- view is your parameter

Comment: **public** is an access specifier,and **void** is a return type......OP is asking about the functionality of the **View** class's parameter here and its significance of passing it in **sendMessage()**

Comment: what is passed to the method by this parameter? @iDev

Comment: view is reffering to the button that was clicked

Comment: you need not calling outside. method call automatically by Android OS internally.

Comment: when you are calling this method compiler expects an object of type Class View. The object is actually called as parameter/Argument

Answer (score 0):

check in xml there are declare Sendmessage button or imageview. and set its property to `android:onClick="sendMessage";`. so send message is not userdefined method but its a listner method on button or imageview click. so there are `View view` parameter pass in method.

in that case we con not need to create object and findviewbyid and setonclicklistener class..

thats it....