# why onClick method gets view as parameter?

Tags: android

I'm new in android world but I have some Java knowledge and from what what I know in java we pass parameters to methods to be used while this method onClick(View v) seems to get a parameter for absolutely nothing .

```
public interface OnClickListener {
    /**
     * Called when a view has been clicked.
     *
     * @param v The view that was clicked.
     */
    void onClick(View v);
}
```

why not ?

```
public interface OnClickListener {
    /**
     * Called when a view has been clicked.
     *
     * @param v The view that was clicked.
     */
    void onClick();
}
```

alos I want to know how the parameter is even passed there ... for example

```
Button rollButton= findViewById(R.id.rollbutton);

 rollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

// my code
            }
        });
```

when and how  rollButton managed to be passed as parameter in onClick(View v)  ... what's going on exactly and thanks .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing the View class object as a parameter to the method invoked by a button (View view)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971026/passing-the-view-class-object-as-a-parameter-to-the-method-invoked-by-a-button)

Answer (score 0):

i understand your quest

to know how you use the tools you use u must know it's library first

in android the button have many func that help you but it's not have a place you work on it so you must to give him that place every time ( it call view ) that decide where is the activity you work on it

otherwise in xcode when u call button

on button library there are a view it's declare it self unique so 
u not need to decide the view for it

your solution with android

u can do the code you write below

or you need to implement  View.OnClickListener and it will parse the activity ( view ) automatic

and use onClick() for you activity

hope i help u to understand not make it harder